# Пути к изображениям wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Возникла надобность натянуть верстку на Wordpress, за основу взял чистый шаблон, но никак не могу понять как правильно прописать пути к изображениям моей темы и где их правильно хранить, гуглил но ничего внятного не нашел.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно - используя [get_stylesheet_directory_uri](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri). И никаких абсолютных путей и тем более корней сайта! Все файлы темы должны находиться в её каталоге/подкаталогах.

Дом информация: [Создание тем](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC),  [Иерархия шаблонов](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2)

А вообще всегда стоит делать [дочернюю тему](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B).